# Subsonic How to select between date

Tags: select, subsonic

Could anyone tell me how to do the select function in SubSonic project to query all customer who will have birthday in next two week from today.

Table Customer
Name  Thomas
DOB   19/09/1981

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

If you're only using one provider (most people are) and you want to take advantage of the table structs that SubSonic generates for you:

```
CustomerCollection customers = DB.Select().From(Customers.Schema)
  .Where(Customers.Columns.CustomerName).IsEqualTo("Thomas")
  .And(Customers.Columns.DOB).IsBetweenAnd(DateTime.Today, DateTime.Today.AddDays(14))
  .ExecuteAsCollection<CustomerCollection>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
new Select("Provider").From("Customers")
.Where("CustomerName")
.IsEqualTo("Thomas")
.Where("DOB")
.IsBetweenAnd(DateTime.Today, DateTime.Today.AddDays(14));
```

PS:- **Provider** is your SubSonic provider name.

Answer (score 0):

I think I need to explain more on what's I would like to have, I would like to send an email to all customer who birthday is in the next 2 weeks in 3 times, 2 weeks before his/her birthday, 3 days before and 1 days before.

Comment: You *should* be able to edit your question to add this information to it.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, this would be something like

```
select name, dob 
from customer
where datediff(day,getDate(),dob)+1 = 14 
or datediff(day,getDate(),dob)+1 = 3
or datediff(day,getDate(),dob)+1 = 1
```

In SubSonic, you could write this like so:

```
new Select(Customer.NameColumn, Customer.DobColumn)
.From(Customer.Schema)
.Where("datediff(day,getDate(),dob)+1=14")
  .Or("datediff(day,getDate(),dob)+1=3")
  .Or("datediff(day,getDate(),dob)+1=1")
```