# Records between two dates using subsonic

Tags: sql, datetime, subsonic, between

Hy. I have a table with two datetime columns (initialDate, finalDate), and i need to filter records where my variable varDate is between the values of the datetime fields.

it´s simple using SQL: 
`SELECT * FROM Table WHERE varDate BETWEEN initialDate AND finalDate`

but, anyone can answer how do i get these records using a SubSonic Query?

i've just tried every SubSonic statment, but it's just useless.. any method supported just need to compare table fields between values; and what i need its to compare value between table fields.
thanks (and sorry for my english, i'm from Argentina)

Comment: Does this post help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/994656/subsonic-how-to-select-between-date

Comment: In the example you can see the following structure: select, column, comparison, initial date value, final date value. What I need is select date value between initial date column and final date column. thanks for answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
DB.Select().From("Purchase")
            .Where("PurchaseDate").IsBetweenAnd(FromDate.DateTime, ToDate.DateTime)
            .ExecuteAsCollection<PurchaseCollection>();
```